# How to align VBoxes in a SplitPane

Tags: javafx

[image]I have a SplitPane (verticle) at the Center of a BorderPane in my Gui. In my SplitPane  I add an HBox as the top and a FlowPane as the bottom. Everytime I add a set of cards to a VBox and add the VBox to my FlowPane it adds the VBoxes one after the other instead of adding them vertically. Does anyone know why?

```
@FXML
private FlowPane setsArea;

 //sets
public void addSet(CardSet set) {
    VBox setView = new VBox(20);
    for (Card card : set.getCards()) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(card.getImgUrl());
        setView.getChildren().add(imageView);
    }
    setsArea.getChildren().add(setView);
    setViews.put(set, setView);
}
```

My GameView.fxml where I am adding the SplitPane as the center of my BorderPane.

```
   <center>
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-image: url('game.jpg');" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <items>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
           <children>
              <HBox fx:id="playAreaTop" />
           </children></AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
           <children>
              <FlowPane fx:id="setsArea" />
           </children></AnchorPane>
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
</center>
```

How  I am adding the cardSets:

```
 Card card = new Basic(Suit.CLUBS, 4, 1);

        Card card2 = new Basic(Suit.HEARTS, 5, 2);

        Card card3 = new Joker(Suit.JOKER, 15, 3);

        Card card4 = new Ace(Suit.HEARTS, 14, 4);

        ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(card);
        cards.add(card2);
        cards.add(card4);

        CardSet cardSet = new CardSet(cards);

        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
        gameView.addSet(cardSet);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `FlowPane`. Use something else that will layout the `VBoxes` the way you want them. Have you looked up `FlowPane` and how it behaves?

Comment: The only reason I used a FlowPane is because it wraps it's contents to make space

Comment: Try a `GridPane` or maybe `TilePane`.

Comment: To vertically align elements in a FlowPane, you need to set its [orientation property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html#orientationProperty) to Vertical.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in context. And don't forget to read and understand the api doc of all available layouts - that's always the starter for matching layout requirements and to ... well .. layout :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding image into VBox and put them all in a FlowPane don't make them vertically stacked you should replace your FlowPane into a VBox and add the ImageViews to the VBox which stack it's item vertically like so:

```
<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="160.0" style="-fx-background-image: url('game.jpg');" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
<items>
  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
       <children>
          <HBox fx:id="playAreaTop" />
       </children></AnchorPane>
  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
       <children>
          <VBox fx:id="setsArea" />
       </children></AnchorPane>
</items>
```

```
@FXML
private VBox setsArea;

public void addSet(CardSet set){
    for (Card card : set.getCards()) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(card.getImgUrl());
        setsArea.getChildren().add(imageView);
    }
    setViews.put(set, setView);
}
```